# .NET 4.8 not creating a self-contained file for Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, console-application, self-contained

I have a a little .NET Core console application that I would like to make a self-contained file of. Not only that, I would also like to create a self-contained file that will run on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS).

The issue I am having is when I run `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c release --self-contained true` I get multiple files and the files seem to be configured for Windows only. I also tried removing `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`. This makes sure there isn't any EXE file file when publishing, but I still get multiple files that I am not sure if they can even run on CentOS since they are only .dll files. My target framework is set to `<TargetFramework>net4.8</TargetFramework>`.

Here are some visuals of the output I am getting:

Having `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` set in my .csproj:

[image]

Having `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` removed:

[image]

Comment: Framework 4.8 is the windows-only version of .NET. Do you want to be targeting Core?

Comment: You can't target `net4.8` if you want to build a Linux executable. You need a .NET Core target, likely `netcoreapp3.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675194/dotnet-net4-8-not-creating-self-contained-file-for-linux#comment107349595_60675194) [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675194/dotnet-net4-8-not-creating-self-contained-file-for-linux#comment107350547_60675194) by [Jonathon Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5402620/jonathon-chase) and [Herohtar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574531/herohtar), I targeted the wrong framework. The framework I used (`net4.8`) is Windows only.

The correct framework to use would be something like `netcoreapp3.0`.